# IDLE wont start Python 2.6.5

Tags: python, python-idle

I was using it as my primary text editor for quite sometime. However, one day it just stopped working. This had happened to me several times before, so I simply tried to end all procceses using windows task manager. However that didn't work. I've recently tried getting it to work again. Whenever I try to reopen it it informs me that it's subprocess couldn't connect. I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it, yet the problem persists.

Anyone have any other solutions?

Important facts:
Windows 7, Python 2.6.5

Comment: Have you rebooted? What changes have you made to your PC since before it stopped working?

Comment: Yes I have rebooted. I have made changes since it stopped working ~2months ago. However, I didn't make any changes then that would have caused that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I would advise you to stop using IDLE, the fact that it runs program code in the same process as itself caused me a lot of problems when I used it, including things like not refreshing imported modules that were modified. Personally I switched to emacs, but you might like to try something like Notepad++.

Comment: I have Notepad++, how do I run a module on it?

Comment: By default, IDLE now run user code in a separate process.  The process is killed and a new one started fresh each time one selects F5 Run Module in an editor window.   One can also explicitly ask for a restart.  I believe the change was made before this answer was posted, but apparently after Anonymous switched to emacs.